# Combine javascripts from multiple templates with Assetic

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

Suppose I have the following twig templates:

base.html.twig:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts
            '../app/Resources/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'
            '../app/Resources/js/base.js'
            filter='uglifyjs2' output='main.js'
        %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock javascripts %}
    </body>
</html>
```

page1.html.twig:

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts
        '../app/Resources/js/page1_specific.js'
        '../app/Resources/js/page1_other.js'
        filter='uglifyjs2' output='page1.js'
    %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

With this code, `page1` template will make two javascript requests, one for `main.js` and another one for `page1.js`.

Is it possible to write it differently, so I it would generate only one big js file specific to each final template, including the base page js and the `page1` specific js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare in your config.yml the base js, like this:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        base:
        inputs:
            - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'
            - '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/base.js'
```

And call this in your javascript block:

```
{% javascripts
    '@base'
    '../app/Resources/js/page1_specific.js'
    '../app/Resources/js/page1_other.js'
    filter='uglifyjs2' output='page1.js'
%}
```

You can find more [info here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets).